# Rails - new path doesn't work. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to have the URL like `photos/13/rate` => I have created following routing rule:

```
match 'photos/:id/rate' => 'photos#rate'
```

In this case I would assume this path:

```
link_to 'Rate', rate_photos_path(@photo)
```

But I am still getting the error message

```
undefined method `rate_photo_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000012aa18170>:0x0000012aa14520>
```

I tried to print out `rake:routes`, but in the statement is only

```
                       /photos/:id/rate(.:format)                    photos#rate
```

without the path.

What's wrong in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'rate'
  end
end
```

Or you need to give the route a name.

```
match 'photos/:id/rate' => 'photos#rate', :as => :rate_photo
```